# What is the equivalence of EXCEPT ALL in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Suppose we have two tables - a and b, both with 7 rows and 2 columns(id, num).
column 'num' of table a - {1,1,1,2,3,5,7},
column 'num' of table b - {1,1,2,2,4,6,8}.
I want to implement 'except all' for these two columns.
We know under PostgreSQL it should be simple:

```
SELECT num FROM a
EXCEPT ALL
SELECT num FROM b;
```

And the result is - {1,3,5,7}.
We can use IN operator and subquery to implement 'EXCEPT', but how about 'EXCEPT ALL'?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to rank each row for each `num` in both tables and with a `LEFT` join filter out the common rows:

```
WITH 
  ctea AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num) rn FROM a),
  cteb AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY num) rn FROM b)
SELECT a.num
FROM ctea a LEFT JOIN cteb b
ON (b.num, b.rn) = (a.num, a.rn)
WHERE b.num IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0707f5170bc4cbd440699108857e4878).